# Is there a way to tell whether a bash script keeps being executed from disk?

Tags: bash

I've noticed that sometimes a looping bash script seems to be loaded into memory, but sometimes it seems to keep reading it from disk.  I haven't been able to work out which of these will happen given a non-trivial script.

Ordinarily it doesn't matter in practice, but if I'm making changes to the script, sometimes (but, it seems, not always) the running script is broken when I save the changes because apparently it's reading from a particular point in the file and things weren't as it left them!

So I just thought I would ask: is there a way to know whether the script is constantly being read from disk rather than being executed from memory?

A simple script like this one seems to be read in and executed entirely from memory, since changing `abc` to `xyz` and saving does not affect a running instance of the script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while :
do
  echo abc
  sleep 2
done
```

Perhaps it's just a size thing?

Comment: There's no obligation on bash to read the whole script before executing it. If it read till some position X, and while executing that part the file got modified, then bash will continue to read from that position X from the modified file, which might cause problems. Bash does read compound commands and function definitions completely before executing them though, so a simple way out is for the entire script to be wrapped in a`( ... )` or a function definition and then call that function at the end

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It's partly a size thing.</strike> When reading from a regular file, Bash reads a block at a time, similarly to what the C library does, probably a few kilobytes at a time. Then it parses any full lines it got, and executes any *complete* commands it has. But it also seeks the read pointer back to where it left, so it may see modifications to the file even if the file is small. (It doesn't seem to always seek back, though. I'm not sure if it only does that when running an external command.)

So, if you have this:

```
echo one
sleep 123
# filler if needed
echo two
```

and you edit the file in-place during the sleep, you may be able to modify the second `echo` before Bash reads and runs it. Some other shells (like Dash or Busybox) don't seek the read pointer back, so you'd only get the effect if you have a large, multi-kB filler between the commands.

But, if you have

```
main() {
    echo one
    sleep 123
    # really long multi-kB comment
    # ...
    echo two
}
main
```

the shell will  read and store the function in one go, and then run it from memory.

There's also the idiom of having

```
main "$@"; exit
```

as the last line of file. Since Bash reads and parses a full line at once, this makes sure the shell exits after the main function, even if the file is subsequently modified.

Looks like I've written another answer on this before, under [Replacing shell script while running it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/361247/170373). There's an example of a self-modifying script there.

Comment: *probably a few kilobytes at a time* - this is quite wrong from my experience. From what I've seen Bash maybe reads a few lines at the time but I'm too lazy to read the source code. This looks like a deliberate decision because the Linux kernel read ahead buffer is normally at the very least 4KB, and nowadays it's 256KB at least on my x86-64 PC with a ton of RAM.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, yeah, I did add the "but seeks back" when I realized it a moment later. I ran Bash under `strace -e trace=read,lseek` and saw it read 8176 bytes at a time, but seek back before running the `sleep`. (Contrast with Dash that read 8192 bytes and didn't seek back.) Bash does read one byte at a time until end of line if the input is pipe though, because there it can't seek back. I don't think the _kernel_'s buffers matter, it has to provide a consistent view of the file, buffers or not. It's the buffers inside the process that do matter.